# PHP get distinct ids count from an array by date

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Looking for the simplest way to achieve the following in php:

I have this array with dates and ids

```
$data = array(
  array("date" => "2016-01", "ids" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)),
  array("date" => "2016-02", "ids" => array(1,2,9,10,11,12)),
  array("date" => "2016-03", "ids" => array(3,16,17,18,19,20,21)),
  array("date" => "2016-04", "ids" => array(1,2,3,19,20,22,23))
);
```

The idea is to count ids by date but also return count(existing ids) since the start of every month separately. (I hope this is understandable)

The returned array should look like this:

```
$data = array(
  array("date" => "2016-01", "counter" => array(8)),
  array("date" => "2016-02", "counter" => array(2,4)), /* 2 existing ids from 2016-01 and 4 new in 2016-02) */
  array("date" => "2016-03", "counter" => array(1,0,6)), /* 1 existing from 2016-01 and 0 exiting from 2016-02 and 6 new */
  array("date" => "2016-04", "counter" => array(3,0,2,2)) /* etc. */
);



        | 2016-01 | 2016-02 | 2016-03 | 2016-04
------  | ------- | ------- | ------- | -------
2016-01 |     8   |         |         |         
------  | ------- | ------- | ------- | -------
2016-02 |     2   |    4    |         |        
------  | ------- | ------- | ------- | -------
2016-03 |     1   |    0    |    6    |        
------  | ------- | ------- | ------- | -------
2016-04 |     3   |    0    |    2    |    2
```

Of course if there is a way to do that directly in sql i'll take it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. (I'm not sure if it's the simplest). Looping over the set of data is the easiest part.

Within that, consider each id from the current day with `while ($id = array_pop($day['ids']))`. For each of those ids, start at the first day, and look for the id in that days set of ids. If it's found, increment the count for that day and continue with the next id (`continue 2` continues the `while` loop.) If it's not found, move on to the next day. If it's not found when you get to the current day (indicated by `$i < $key` in the `for` loop) then increment the count for the current day and move on to the next id.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $day) {
    $counts = array_fill(0, $key + 1, 0);
    while ($id = array_pop($day['ids'])) {
        for ($i=0; $i < $key; $i++) {
            $past_day = $data[$i];
            if (in_array($id, $past_day['ids'])) {
                $counts[$i]++;
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        $counts[$key]++;
    }
    $new_data[] = ['date' => $day['date'], 'counter' => $counts];
}
```

p.s. I have *no idea* how to do this in SQL.

Comment: Note - that presumes PHP 7 is available, since the [coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) is employed

Comment: @Aelliott1485 I had used the `??` operator earlier, but after I filled the counts array at the beginning, it was no longer needed. But you're right, that was definitely a PHP 7 only thing. Current version should be ok with 5.4+.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know this operator. But yes i can't use PHP 7

Comment: @mchev This answer no longer uses that operator, and should work fine on PHP 5.

Comment: @Don'tPanic nice, may i ask if i work with an object (curiosity)?

Comment: @mchev I'm not totally sure what you mean. You mean if `$data` is an object rather than an array? Or to create an object as the result rather than an array?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes sorry, if $data is an object

Comment: @mchev It could still work, but a couple of things would need to change. The necessary changes would depend on the overall structure of the object (if some levels were arrays, property accessibility, etc.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Something like array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(7) "2016-01"
    ["ids"]=>
    string(4) "1,2,3,4"
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to achieve the desired result,

```
$newArray = array();
$count = count($data);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
    $newArray[$i] = array('date' => $data[$i]['date'], 'counter' => array());
    for($j = 0; $j < $i; ++$j){
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($data[$i]['ids'] as $key => $id){
            if(in_array($id, $data[$j]['ids'])){
                ++$counter;
                unset($data[$i]['ids'][$key]);
            }
        }
        $newArray[$i]['counter'][] = $counter;
    }
    $newArray[$i]['counter'][] = count($data[$i]['ids']);
}

// display $newArray array
var_dump($newArray);
```

---

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/657257)